# how did 2 javascript dev's habits coexisted together?

Tags: javascript

I heard that once JavaScript developers used to put the link to the script at the top of the page. if that was the case how did they grabbed elements from the document?

Comment: They wrap their code in a function body that will only be executed **after** the whole page (DOM) was loaded.

Comment: Sometimes links to scripts are *still* put in the `<head>`.